# Unity : Tags to Layers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, select, tags, layer

I want to make a selection script in unity 3d to select different types of objects
like units buildings or other stuff
i want to know how to change this type of line

```
 if(hit.transform.CompareTag("Unit"))
 {
     SelectUnits(hit.transform);
 }
 else 
 {
     DeselectUnits();
 }
```

I want to use layers not tags for this and i don't know how to change this line
" if(hit.transform.CompareTag("Unit")) " into  a line using layerMask not Tags in declarations.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use layer either for discriminate them. Use layer for it's purpose.

if you're dealing with components use `Component.TryGetComponent`. If not then just simply check is-a relationship between classes.

```
 if(hit.transform.TryGetComponent(out AbstractUnit unit))
 {
    unit.SelectUnity();
 }
 else 
 {
    DeselectUnits();
 }
```